# How to list only reviewed movies?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem here. I created a database with different tables. I have a table named "movie" with 108 movies. This table includes columns
"id, name, director, year, country",
table named "reviews" which includes columns
"movie_id" (movie_id links to the id of movie which was reviewed),
"review_score" (1 to 5 points),
"review (with review text)",
"critics_id" (which links to the critics from critics-table),
and also table named "critics" which icludes columns
"critics_name" and "critics_id".
The problem is that there is over 100 movies but only 10 of them are reviewed and I have to list only reviewed movies but reviews and movies are in different tables. When I try simple command SELECT name, review FROM movie, reviews - I get a huge list with repeating movies (see on picture) [my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRI7K.png)
Is there any command which could list only reviewed movies and so that every reviewed movie would be in the list only once?
Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score -1):

This is where you use a join. You'd select from the movie table and join the reviews table, then filter by movies that have a joined review.

For example:

```
SELECT movie.*, review.review_score, review.review
FROM movie
LEFT JOIN reviews AS review
  ON review.movie_id = movie.movie_id -- assuming this column name is correct...
WHERE review.movie_id IS NOT NULL
```

You could also add another join to your critics table:

```
SELECT movie.*, review.review_score, review.review, critic.critics_name
FROM ....
LEFT JOIN critics AS critic
  ON critic.critics_id = review.critics_id
WHERE critic.critics_id IS NOT NULL
```

Please note that this example uses [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) to highlight the way that the join works, in that if it doesn't find a match then the joined result will be null.

If you used an [inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) instead, you wouldn't get any results that don't match the `on` clause, and as such you wouldn't need the `WHERE id IS NOT NULL` parts at all.

An inner joined example of the above would return movies that are reviewed, as well as the critic's name:

```
SELECT movie.*, review.review_score, review.review, critic.critics_name
FROM movie
INNER JOIN reviews AS review
  ON review.movie_id = movie.id
INNER JOIN critics AS critic
  ON critic.critics_id = review.critics_id
```

Also - I'm using `AS` to alias the plural table names to a singular name purely for semantic reasons. You could continue to use `reviews` and `critics` if you wanted to without the `AS` aliases.

Comment: Thank u very much. I changed the code you gave me to
 SELECT movie.*, reviews.review_score, reviews.review
FROM movie
LEFT JOIN reviews AS reviews
ON reviews.movie_id = movie.id WHERE reviews.movie_id IS NOT NULL;
and it works!

Answer (score -2):

Hope below query helps you:

```
SELECT
  m.name,
  c.critics_name,
  r.review_score,
  r.review_text
FROM movies m
  JOIN reviews r ON r.movie_id = m.id
  JOIN critics c ON c.critics_id = r.critics_id
```

for distinct movies change query as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.name
FROM movies m
  JOIN reviews r ON r.movie_id = m.id
  JOIN critics c ON c.critics_id = r.critics_id
```